# Simple list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Suppose I have a list:

```
 [(red, red, 1),
 (red, blue, 3),
 (red, yellow, 2),
 (blue, red, 3),
 (blue, blue, 1),
 (blue, yellow, 4),
 (yellow, red, 2),
 (yellow, blue, 4),
 (yellow, yellow, 1)]
```

What is the easiest way to get a pandas dataframe like this?

```
             red    blue   yellow
red           1       3       2                               
blue          3       1       4
yellow        2       4       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DataFrame constructor with pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), last remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L).pivot(0,1,2).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
        blue  red  yellow
blue       1    3       4
red        3    1       2
yellow     4    2       1
```